# Viewing the contents in <function1> from the scala repl

Tags: scala

I can create anonymous functions in the scala repl like so:

```
scala> val a = (x: Int) => x * x
a: Int => Int = <function1>
```

But is there anyway of seeing what is inside  after it has been created?

I'm thinking about situations where I would take a function and return a function. I'm just curious to see what the repl created as the return, rather than just the type of the returned value, so something like:

```
scala> val b = (f: (Int => Boolean)) => (x: Int) => ! (f(x))
b: (Int => Boolean) => (Int => Boolean) = <function1>

scala> val c = b((x: Int) => x % 2 == 0)
c: Int => Boolean = <function1>
```

I want to see what code has been generated inside c!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done outside of the REPL, but you can compile your code using scalac with the -print option. Doing `scalac -help` will give you this description of the option:

```
-print        Print program with Scala-specific features removed.
```

I tried it with this small program:

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val a = (x: Int) => x * x
    }
}
```

And it gave me this output:

```
$ scalac -print Test.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                   cleanup]] // Test.scala
package <empty> {
  object Test extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val a: Function1 = {
        (new <$anon: Function1>(): Function1)
      };
      ()
    };
    def <init>(): Test.type = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  @SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class anonfun$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp with Serializable {
    final def apply(x: Int): Int = anonfun$1.this.apply$mcII$sp(x);
    <specialized> def apply$mcII$sp(x: Int): Int = x.*(x);
    final <bridge> <artifact> def apply(v1: Object): Object = scala.Int.box(anonfun$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)));
    def <init>(): <$anon: Function1> = {
      anonfun$1.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not as handy as [same functionality in, say, clojure](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.repl/source), since it shows *compiled code* but you can either get advantage of `:javap`:

```
scala> :javap -help
usage       :javap [opts] [path or class or -]...
-help       Prints this help message
-raw        Don't unmangle REPL names
-app        Show the DelayedInit body of Apps
-fun        Show anonfuns for class or Class#method
-verbose/-v Stack size, number of locals, method args
-private/-p Private classes and members
-package    Package-private classes and members
-protected  Protected classes and members
-public     Public classes and members
-l          Line and local variable tables
-c          Disassembled code
-s          Internal type signatures
-sysinfo    System info of class
-constants  Static final constants

scala> :javap -s a
Compiled from "<console>"
public class  {
  public static final  MODULE$;
    descriptor: L;
  public static {};
    descriptor: ()V

  public scala.Function1<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> a();
    descriptor: ()Lscala/Function1;

  public ();
    descriptor: ()V
}
```

Or instruct REPL to output code internals on compilation with `scala -Xprint:typer` (though it might be overly verbose, maybe someone can suggest less wordy compiler stage to use).

BTW, as you can see in :javap output, every REPL expression is implicitly wrapped with surrounding code, don't be confused -- scala does not perform it normally.

Comment: Well, that's a start! Will leave the question open and see if anyone else has an insight, but I suspect this is the best we get with the repl! Thank you :)

Comment: Doesn't seem that anyone else knows! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Kat: if I understand your question correctly, then `javap` is really no help here, because every function returned by `b` has _the same code_ in it. The functions returned differ only because they close over different values of `f`.  (Your question, especially your use of the word "generated", makes me wonder if you are envisioning a different underlying mechanism.)

Answer (score 5):

To see function literals, use `:javap -fun`:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def f = (1 to 10) map (_ * 2)
f: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]

scala> :javap -fun f
Compiled from "<console>"
public final class $anonfun$f$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp implements scala.Serializable {
  public static final long serialVersionUID;
  public final int apply(int);
  public int apply$mcII$sp(int);
  public final java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object);
  public $anonfun$f$1();
}
```

That's the anonymous function passed to map.

To filter for the apply methods, which are the body of the function, use a trailing `#` or `f#apply`:

```
scala> :javap -fun f#
  public final int apply(int);
  public int apply$mcII$sp(int);
  public final java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object);
```

That includes specialized methods.

```
scala> :javap -fun -prv f#
  public final int apply(int);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: iload_1       
         2: invokevirtual #21                 // Method apply$mcII$sp:(I)I
         5: ireturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       6     0  this   L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$f$1;
               0       6     1   x$1   I
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
  public int apply$mcII$sp(int);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: iload_1       
         1: iconst_2      
         2: imul          
         3: ireturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       4     0  this   L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$f$1;
               0       4     1   x$1   I
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
  public final java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: aload_1       
         2: invokestatic  #32                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
         5: invokevirtual #34                 // Method apply:(I)I
         8: invokestatic  #38                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        11: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0      12     0  this   L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$f$1;
               0      12     1    v1   Ljava/lang/Object;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0

scala>
```

For vals, first look at the constructor for the evaluation:

```
scala> :javap -fun c
Failed: No closures found.

scala> :javap -prv c
[snip]
  public $line7.$read$$iw$$iw$();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #20                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: putstatic     #22                 // Field MODULE$:L$line7/$read$$iw$$iw$;
         8: aload_0       
         9: getstatic     #27                 // Field $line6/$read$$iw$$iw$.MODULE$:L$line6/$read$$iw$$iw$;
        12: invokevirtual #30                 // Method $line6/$read$$iw$$iw$.b:()Lscala/Function1;
        15: new           #32                 // class $line7/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1
        18: dup           
        19: invokespecial #33                 // Method $line7/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1."<init>":()V
        22: invokeinterface #39,  2           // InterfaceMethod scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
[snip]
```

and then cut/paste the name of the anonfun, optionally adding the `#` to filter for just the apply methods:

```
scala> :javap -prv $line7/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1#
  public final boolean apply(int);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: iload_1       
         2: invokevirtual #18                 // Method apply$mcZI$sp:(I)Z
         5: ireturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       6     0  this   L$line7/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1;
               0       6     1     x   I
      LineNumberTable:
        line 12: 0
  public boolean apply$mcZI$sp(int);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: iload_1       
         1: iconst_2      
         2: irem          
         3: iconst_0      
         4: if_icmpne     11
         7: iconst_1      
         8: goto          12
        11: iconst_0      
        12: ireturn       
[snip]
```

The function stored in `c`:

```
scala> $intp.isettings.unwrapStrings = false
$intp.isettings.unwrapStrings: Boolean = false

scala> c.getClass
res4: Class[_ <: Int => Boolean] = class $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1

scala> :javap -prv $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1
[snip]
```

The `-raw` option for `:javap` exposes the REPL's packages and wrapping objects. To see them in ordinary output, you have to turn off output filtering as shown.

Or:

```
scala> $intp.withoutUnwrapping(println(c.getClass))
class $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1
```

Usually anon funs are brief, so filtering for the apply method is not necessary.

Note that I stripped out this feature for the transition to Java 8 lambdas, since the encoding has been in flux. Maybe it will be restored at some point.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing at runtime which will print compiled code nicely.

You could write a macro which will print the source code of the tree and use that? Most macro tutorials start with a macro for printing source code -- see e.g. http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/12/starting-with-scala-macros-a-short-tutorial/

Perhaps:

```
// Given a partial function "pf", return the source code for pf
// as a string as well as the compiled, runnable function itself
def functionAndSource(pf: PartialFunction[Any, Any]): (String, PartialFunction[Any, Any]) = macro functionAndSourceImpl

def functionAndSourceImpl = ...

val pm1: (String, PartialFunction[Any, Any]) = functionAndSource {
  case "foo" => R1
}
```

This isn't ever going to be that easy or nice in Scala. Scala isn't Lisp or Ruby: it's a compiled language and it is not optimised for reflection on the code itself.

(See [Scala Pattern Matching pretty printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037347) for a very similar question.)

Answer (score 3):

Try my small [scala-to-java](https://github.com/Aivean/scala-to-java) tool. It complies given scala source and then decompiles it into java using [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler) decompiler.

For you scala input:

```
val a = (x: Int) => x * x
```

It shows this decompiled output:

```
import scala.*;
import scala.runtime.*;

public final class _$$anon$1$$anonfun$1 extends AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp implements Serializable {
    @Override
    public final int apply(final int x) {
        return this.apply$mcII$sp(x);
    }

    @Override
    public int apply$mcII$sp(final int x) {
        return x * x;
    }
}

import scala.*;

public final class _$$anon$1 {
    private final Function1<Object, Object> a = new _$$anon$1$$anonfun._$$anon$1$$anonfun$1(this);

    private Function1<Object, Object> a() {
        return (Function1<Object, Object>)this.a;
    }
}
```